# What is the name of this special definition syntax in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was reading the ReactJS source code in Github and I noticed that the React team use an special syntax when they define a type.

The special syntax looks like this:

```
type Example = {|
  id: string
|};
```

Is the `{| |}` part of the type definition a Javascript named feature? Or Is it something related to the use of a typing extension (Flow/Typescript) in the React codebase?

In any case I really want to know the name of this feature whether if it's directly related to Javascript or not because after an extensive research in Google I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I don't think this is javascript

Comment: can you link to where in the source they do this? You can probably tell by the file extension or a pragma at the top of the file

Comment: Here you can see it better: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5f06576f51ece88d846d01abd2ddd575827c6127/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiber.js#L85

Comment: @coagmano I see the `@flow` annotation at the very top of the file but the file extension is `.js`

Comment: thanks, looks like a flow thing then, I'll go look at their docs... And @mobigaurav has already found and answered :D

Comment: Good question, I learned something new

Answer (score 3):

This is Flowtype's Exact Object type syntax. Look at here: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types